# jquery-ui button not workin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

## html

```
<input type="checkbox" name="bar" value="1" id="id_bar" />
<label for="id_bar">Bar</label>
```

## static files

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/vendor/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/overcast/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.css" />
```

## script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
    try{
        $(checkboxes).button();     
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

## doubt

i am not getting any errors , the script is running just fine , but even after executing the command , there are no changes to the checkboxes , please help.

Comment: The html+js parts work fine for me in jsFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aUQNg/ So my guess is it's a problem with your references.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for buttonset not button

from [jquery ui docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Button): radio and checkbox use buttonset()

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#radio").buttonset();
  })
```

Comment: both of them are not working , i have tried putting all the checkboxes inside a div and then calling buttonset() method on that div as directed in the docs , but even thats not working

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$(checkboxes).click();
```

Comment: sorry to say but , i meant that '$(checkboxes).click();' is working, not the .button() method

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
   try{
       checkboxes.button();      
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      alert(e);
   }
});
```

Or Alternately

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   try{
       $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index){
           $(this).button();   
       });     
   }
   catch(e)
   {
      alert(e);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried these ?

```
var checkboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
```

and

```
checkboxes.button();
```

**update**
or

```
checkboxes.buttonset();
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
<form>
    <div id="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">Choice 1</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Choice 2</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio3" name="radio" /><label for="radio3">Choice 3</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

and then

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#radio" ).buttonset();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yea but still its not working , i wonder how both of these are different??

Comment: sorry , its not working and its really not supposed to , because according to the documentation , you need to put all the checkboxes inside a div and then call .buttonset() method on it , [have a look at the documentation example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/)

Comment: And why you have not used from documentation ?

Comment: i have tried that aswell , but thats the point , its not working , and  the worst part is that  both the .buttonset() and .button() methods are called without running into any error

Comment: Then use Google Chrome and press F12 and watch to Console... You may get an error or warning and you don't know. If you want to print something to console, type `console.log('message here');` in your javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an over statement, but Jquery UI is not friendly when it comes with styling buttons and forms.

I suggest http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/  because they use simple class styling.

Back to answering your question.
var checkboxes usually means there are multiple checkboxes.
So maybe use an .each()?

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index, value) {
  $(this).click();
});
```

And you can use $(this).is(':checked') to see if the checkbox is checked or not if you want.

Comment: yea i am using bootstrap , but to convert checkboxes to buttons , i am using jquery ui